# C++ link error for boost::filesystem

Tags: c++, boost, linker-errors

global destructor keyed to (commands.cpp)
undefined reference to boost::system::get_system_category()

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 2):

You need to link to the [Boost.System](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/system/doc/index.html) library as well. It is a dependency of Boost.Filesystem in later releases of Boost.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include boost_system into you link libraries.